# Liferay: Preventing a specific role from adding a specific portlet

Tags: permissions, liferay, portlet, roles

I have a custom portlet that I have developed. I'd like only the admin role to be able to add it to a page. The problem is that the option to add the portlet appears in the Dockbar->Add->More menu for all users. How can I prevent anyone other than the Admin from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following procedure should make it:

1. Login as Administrator
2. Go to Control Panel -> Plugins Configuration (make sure Portlet Plugin is selected on top menu)
3. Search for your portlet name and click it
4. In the Permissions table remove all Roles less then Administrator
5. Save

The following link fragment is a shortcut for starting at step 3 in Liferay 6:

```
[YOUR_SERVER_PROTOCOL_AND_ADDRESS]/group/control_panel/manage?p_p_id=132&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=maximized&p_p_mode=view&doAsGroupId=10156&refererPlid=10159
```

Comment: Thanks! I've been hunting for that for 1/2 a day now. What documentation should I refer to for things like this? I'm just starting out with Liferay development and am reading Liferay in Action and the official online docs (http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development). I din't see these steps mentioned anywhere. Or maybe I just missed it.

Comment: http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide that's for Liferay 6.1

Comment: As an alternative, you could also do Control Panel->Portal->Roles->[Role]->Define Permissions and set permissions there. I'm sure I went to this page and unchecked the "Add to Page" action without any result. But it works now! Anyways, thanks.